# How to get Jekyll category blog listings with jekyll-archive

Tags: jekyll

I installed the Jekyll plugin `jekyll-archives` and I set this up in the `config.yml` file:

```
jekyll-archives:
  enabled: []
  layout: archive
  permalinks:
    category: 'category/:name/'
```

However, I can't get the category listings to show up when I visit `category/category-name` I just get 404. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set `enabled` to `all` and to create a layout called `archive`. Code that worked for me:

```
jekyll-archives:
  enabled: all
  layout: archive
  permalinks:
    category: '/category/:name/'
```